# Binding entity to a specific persistence-unit with 2 datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have two persistence-unit in `persistence.xml` and two datasource in `standalone.xml` but I can't bind table A to persistence 1 and table B to persistence 2

like this

```
<persistence-unit name="itsetup-persistence-unit-dev1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/itsetup-dev1</jta-data-source>
    ...

<persistence-unit name="itsetup-persistence-unit-dev3" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/itsetup-dev3</jta-data-source>
    <class>my.package.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    ...
```

and

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/itsetup-dev3" pool-name="itsetup-dev3" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:informix-sqli://server:9991/database</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>ifxjdbc.jar</driver>
    <security>
    ...
```

and this is my user model

```
@Entity
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "itsetup-persistence-unit-dev3")
@Table(name = "user_file")
public class User {
```

where my user service has

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "itsetup-persistence-unit-dev3")
private EntityManager em;
```

and the course table is

```
@Entity
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "itsetup-persistence-unit-dev1")
@Table(name = "ppp_course")
public class Course {
```

and my course service

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "itsetup-persistence-unit-dev1")
private EntityManager em;
```

but when I run the server, it always generate other table into dev3 database like it did not look into dev1 database `Table not found: ppp_course`

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />` of `<persistence-unit name="itsetup-persistence-unit-dev3" transaction-type="JTA">`. But have to lose the autodetection function.